# Trigger change event of an InputBox when the value set programatically

Tags: jquery, html

How to trigger `OnChange` event of a InputBox when the value of this InputBox  is changed with the value coming from a SelectBox ?? Currently it is not working.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#textbal').val(this.value);
  var a = this.value;
  $('#textball').attr('value', a);

});
$('textball').trigger('change', function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="bal" id="textbal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the event handler using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)  and use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to execute the event handler.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#textbal').val($(this).val()).trigger('change');
});
$('#textbal').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="bal" id="textbal" />
```

Comment: You can also use .change() instead of .on('change') and trigger('change') https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @Zorken17, `.change( handler )` is just a shorthand for `.on( "change", handler )`

Comment: I know, it was only a suggestion on a "shorter" way of writing.

Answer (score -1):

Do Something Like This

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <select>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="bal" id="textbal" onchange="Change()"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').on('change', function() {
              $('#textbal').val( this.value );
              debugger;
              var a = this.value;

              alert(a);

              $('#textball').attr('value',a);
              $('#textbal').trigger('change');
            });

            function  Change()
            {
               alert('Hii');
            }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can not call the function Change by .trigger('change')

Comment: Lol Then Try it first then reply

Comment: no it dose not! First of all change and Change are not the same. Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @Zorken17 if you are not sure about anything please try it first

Comment: @Zorken17 I have tried that code first and its working

Comment: Not Working In Fiddle but it Works when you create a file and write it in that

Comment: Trust me, there are so many wrongs in that code so it will not work.

Comment: Will you plese Copy and Paste the Code in Editor and the run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133419/discussion-between-zorken17-and-ghanshyam-singh).

Comment: Hi all, I need something different.I need on change event in the text field when the value is updated in the text field. suppose you browse a path of folder and it is replace the previous one in the text field at that moment a trigger will be fired for the text input field only